# In which library is the state information typically stored in a React-written application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

so the question on title, do you know where state is stored? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

React let’s you choose, you can either use:

- React’s own state functionality (useState or useReducer hooks)
- as your app grows you might look into libraries like React Redux and Mobx Statetree to structure and handle your state.

React Redux is the de facto standard, whereas Mobx Statetree is generally considered easier to use (and just as powerful).

Answer (score 1):

In react state works Inside a component only , every component has its own state , But if you want to access one components state in other component than you have to pass state as props or you have other options like ContextApi or you can use state management libraries like redux , flux ....

If you are using a state management library, your states are stored inside one store HOC.